# Add a category to a pandas multiIndex dataframe level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Right now I have a dataframe (df) whos structure can be reproduced by doing :

```
d = {('Control', 0, 'mean'): {'Field 1': 1.0},
     ('Control', 0, 'stErr'): {'Field 1': 0.0},
     ('Control', 0, 'stdev'): {'Field 1': 0.0},
     ('Control', 48, 'mean'): {'Field 1': 1.08},
     ('Control', 48, 'stErr'): {'Field 1': 0.01},
     ('Control', 48, 'stdev'): {'Field 1': 0.03},
     ('Test1', 0, 'mean'): {'Field 1': 1.00},
     ('Test1', 0, 'stErr'): {'Field 1': 0.00},
     ('Test1', 0, 'stdev'): {'Field 1': 0.00},
     ('Test1', 48, 'mean'): {'Field 1': 1.08},
     ('Test1', 48, 'stErr'): {'Field 1': 0.01},
     ('Test1', 48, 'stdev'): {'Field 1': 0.03}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
```

I would like to add another category 'ratio' to the dataframe at the level where mean, stErr, and stdev currently exist.

Currently the index looks like this :

```
df.index()
MultiIndex(levels=[['Control', 'Test1'], [0, 48], ['mean', 'stErr', 'stdev']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

To clarify where I'd like to add the category ratio I believe the index of the new dataframe would look like this

```
df_new.index()
MultiIndex(levels=[['Control', 'Test1'], [0, 48], ['mean', 'stErr', 'stdev', 'ratio']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: does `df.index=df.index.set_levels(['mean','stErr','stdev','ratio'],level=2)` do what you want?

Comment: @VictorChubukov that seems to be invalid syntax. `df.index =df .index.set_levels(['mean', 'stErr', 'stdev', 'ratio'‌​], level=2)
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`

Comment: You have an extra space

Comment: got it ... the index looks right but ratio isn't actually in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a `pd.MultiIndex`, `mux`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[['Control', 'Test1'],
            [0, 48],
            ['mean', 'stErr', 'stdev']],
    labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]],
    names=['device', 'interval', None])
```

You can use `set_levels`

```
mux.set_levels(['mean', 'stErr', 'stdev', 'ratio'], level=2, inplace=True)
```

But then you need to follow up with setting the labels as well.

This is a questionably clever way.

```
mux = mux.to_series().unstack([0, 1]) \
         .append(pd.Series(None, name='ratio')) \
         .unstack().index
```

Comment: How does this actually get applied to the dataframe?

Comment: Your question shows that you want a new `pd.MultiIndex`.  If you want something else, you should take the time to demonstrate what you want specifically.  Read this for guidance http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was showing the index to help describe the layout of the dataframe.  I will provide futher clarification.